# euclidean distance in Voronoi polygons

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangulation, voronoi-diagram

Let be $E$ the set of $n \choose 2$ straight line segments ( edges ).

The region $V(i) = \{ x \in E^2 \vert d(x, v_i) \leq d(x, v_j), j = 1,\dots,N\}$

is called Voronoi polygon associated with the vertex $v_i$.

How is the euclidean distance $d(x, v_j)$ between $x=(e_1, e_2)$ and a vertex $v_j$ defined?

The definitions come from

*Lee, D. T.; Schachter, B. J.*, [**Two algorithms for constructing a Delaunay triangulation**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00977785), Int. J. Comput. Inform. Sci. 9, 219-242 (1980). [ZBL0441.68047](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0441.68047).

Comment: The Euclidean distance is simply $ \sqrt{ (x - v_j) \cdot (x - v_j) }$ (where the "$\cdot$" denotes the dot product.

Comment: hmm i see, but what is for example for $x=(e_1, e_2)=(\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix})$ and the point $v_j = (2,2)$ the difference $(x-v_j)$ ?

Comment: $x$ is a $2$ dimensional vector, not a pair of vectors.

Comment: okay, I thought because E is the set of "edges" between vertices (points) in the euclidean space, $x=(e_1 ,e_2)$ has to be a pair of vectors due to $x \in E^2$.